# can't use omnipay package with laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, omnipay

I'd like to install **omnipay**. The first thing I tried was to install `league/omnipay 3 version`, which installs `omnipay/common 3` version. Now the gateway I need is `omnipay-paymentsense` which has requirement of `omnipay/common 2` version. Which means I can't install both `omnipay-paymentsense and omnipay/league` because one uses **common-3,** and another uses **common-2**.(conflict happened)

So then I tried to only install `omnipay-paymentsense` since it already has **common 2.*** requirement. Now, It really started screaming about:

> Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
>
> Conclusion: remove symfony/http-foundation v4.4.1 Conclusion: don't
>   install symfony/http-foundation v3.4.35
>
> Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation 4.2.x-dev|install
>   symfony/http-foundation v3.4.35|install symfony/http-foundation
>   v3.4.36
>       - laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev requires symfony/http-foundation ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.4.1, 4.1.x-dev,
>   4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.0-BETA1, v4.1.0-BETA2, v4.1.0-BETA3, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3,
>   v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1,
>   v4.2.0-BETA2, v4.2.0-RC1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2,
>   v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0,
>   v4.3.0-BETA1, v4.3.0-BETA2, v4.3.0-RC1, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3,
>   v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.0-BETA1,
>   v4.4.0-BETA2, v4.4.0-RC1].
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation 4.3.x-dev|install symfony/http-foundation v3.4.35|install symfony/http-foundation v3.4.36